# How do we log requests with AFNetworking 3.0

Tags: afnetworking, afnetworking-3

How do we log requests with AFNetworking 3.x? It looks like AFNetworkActivityLogger is for AFNetworking 2.x

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this line in your `podfile` and run `pod install` :

```
pod 'AFNetworkActivityLogger', git: 'https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworkActivityLogger.git', branch: '3_0_0'
```

Read more about this because some of the methods in 2.x has been moved to other places.
https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworkActivityLogger/tree/3_0_0#2x---3x-migration